# How to find a PDF form field type

Tags: excel, pdf-form, vba

It appears that documentation for adobe attributes / methods are lacking.  I have the Adobe SDK API but it is lacking any detail.

I have code that is writing data from an Excel document to a PDF form.  It loops through all the fields and writes the data to the PDF form.  If the PDF form field type is numeric I throws and error.

I need to test if the PDF form field is numeric.  If it is I will add that field name to a collection and display once the process is complete.

I looked for GetField properties but can't find any documentation.  Something like:

```
IF jso.getfield(strField).type=numeric
colFail.Add=strField
```

Comment: I put an error handler in the loop that hops out of the loop and records the field name that caused the error.  I then display the fields names that errored once the process is complete.  That works well for what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

AFter reviewing the link the Peh provided (thank you Peh); this is how I handled it:

```
           'Fill the form fields.
            For r = 20 To 149
                strField = ToPDFsh.Cells(r, 3).Value
                strFieldVal = ToPDFsh.Cells(r, 4).Value
                    If strFieldVal = "" Then GoTo BlankVal

                objJSO.GetField(strField).Value = strFieldVal

                On Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

BlankVal:
                Next r`

blah blah blah... then

```
ErrHandler:
e = e + 1
If e > 7 Then
    MsgBox "Something Bad happend... :(" & vbNewLine & "Form not filled", vbCritical, "Failed"
    GoTo ErrHandlerExit
End If

colFail.Add strField
Resume Next
Exit Sub
```

ErrHandlerExit:
    'Close the form without saving the changes.
    objAcroAVDoc.Close True

```
'Close the Acrobat application.
objAcroApp.Exit

'Release the objects and exit.
Set objJSO = Nothing
Set objAcroPDDoc = Nothing
Set objAcroAVDoc = Nothing
Set objAcroApp = Nothing

'Enable the screen.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
```

End Sub